# Check start end end points are same in Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there is any way to check whether start and end positions are the same locations using Google Maps Api v3.

Here is my latitude and longitude ,

```
Start Point : 41.30395, -72.92671 

End Point :  41.3039500,-72.9267090
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the LatLng class's equals function:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

```
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(41.30395, -72.92671);
var end = new google.maps.LatLng(41.3039500,-72.9267090);

alert(start.equals(end));
```

Alternatively if you want to check that two locations are 'approximately' equal, define how many decimal places you want to round your coordinates to.  Round your coordinates then compare them.

```
    var startLat = start.lat();
    var endLat = end.lat();
    var startLng = start.lng();
    var endLng = end.lng();

    // round to 3dp:
    startLat = startLat.toFixed(3);
    endLat = endLat.toFixed(3);
    startLng = startLng.toFixed(3);
    endLng = endLng.toFixed(3);

    console.log(startLat === endLat && startLng === endLng);
    console.log(startLat);
    console.log(endLat);
    console.log(startLng);
    console.log(endLng);
```

Comment: 41.30395, -72.92671 & 41.3039500,-72.9267090 both latitude and longitude represents same location approximately. Then `start.equals(end)` giving `false` , It is may be difference after 4 or 3rd digit after decimal. Can i make latitude and longitude round upto 3rd digit after decimal point ?

Comment: You can define 'small enough difference' and use it as a check when you subtract/check values.

Comment: @AntoJurković Thanks , Can you please explain this ?

Comment: For example you save a marker with some lat/lng. When you retrieve those values there could be very small difference after 5th, 6th, 7th ... decimal point. Depends on example. So, you can say that if the difference between what you set and what you get is less than for example 0.000001, then the value is the same.

Comment: @NishantN. see my updated answer rounding the values to 3dp to compare if they are approximately equal